# DB Design | Many to Many - companies & customers locations

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Let's assume I have those tables:

- companies (id, name, phone, email)
- customers (id, name, phone, email)
- locations (id, city, state)

Each company and each customer can have multiple locations.

What is the best & fastest way to create the above relationships, assuming that in my application I will need to search for all companies that are related to at least one location of customer's locations with id=N and vice versa?

---

Couldn't find a more generic title, feel free to change it to some generic one.

Comment: Is there any relationship with company & customer?

Comment: @Mittal nope, there is no relationship between them

Answer (score 3):

As my opinion you can create table as below:

- locations (id, city, state)
- companies (id, name, phone, email)
- companylocations (id, CompanyId, locationId) - Foreign key with companies & locations table
- customers (id, name, phone, email)
- customerlocations (id, customerId, locationId) - Foreign key with customers & locations table

Add indexes to below columns to fetch data faster

- customerlocations (customerId, locationId)
- companylocations (CompanyId, locationId)

`id` column for all the tables would be primary key so we have an index on that.

Comment: That's what I thought, but will it be fast enough when searching as I described before? And how do I search that anyway? It would probably contain multiple JOINs which will cause bad preformance.

Comment: If you add proper indexes then your search would be faster, and I think you need maximum 2-4 join to achieve this and it would be fine

Comment: You're struggling with 4th Normal Form. You need a separate intersection table for each many-to-many relationship. Both answers below that tell you this are correct.

Answer (score 1):

> You can build some junction table for the company and the customers.

```
Companies  
id (pk)
name
phone
email

Companies_location
id (pk)
company_id (reference to Companies table id) (fk)
location_id (reference to  Location Table id) (fk)

Customers
id (pk)
name
phone
email

Customers_location
id (pk)
customer_id (reference to Customers table id) (fk)
location_id (reference to  Location Table id) (fk)

Location
id (pk)
state
city
```

> **SQL Statement :**

```
You can use Union because they have same field.
```

Comment: That's not what I asked for.. Read my question again.

Comment: im so srry i miss understood the problem but hope it helps